# Nested resolves: update a single item in a collection?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

In my AngularJS/Restangular app I have a messages module where you can view a list of conversations and an individual conversation:

```
angular.module('messages').config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('messages', {
        url: '/messages/',
        templateUrl: '/messages/list.html',
        controller: 'MessagesListCtrl as controller',
        resolve: {
            'conversations': ['Restangular', function(Restangular) {
                return Restangular.all('conversations').getList();
            }]
        }
    });

    $stateProvider.state('messages.detail', {
        url: ':conversationId/',
        templateUrl: '/messages/conversation.html',
        controller: 'MessagesDetailCtrl as controller',
        resolve: {
            'conversation': ['conversations', 'Restangular', '$stateParams', '$state', function(conversations, Restangular, $stateParams, $state) {
                return conversations.get($stateParams.conversationId).then(function(data) {
                    Restangular.restangularizeCollection(data, data.messages, 'messages');
                    return data;
                }, function() {
                    $state.go('messages');
                });
            }]
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see I have nested states, the list template contains a ui-view for the detail template. I use resolves so the content doesn't pop into place. Now here's the question:

In the list view I'm showing unread conversations with a badge by using the `conversation.unreadItems` property.

In the detail view controller I want to mark that conversation as read: `conversation.unreadItems = false;` (I'm also doing a PUT to the server). How do I get the list view to update as well, so the badge is removed?

I though that the detail's `conversation` object would be part of the list's `conversations` collection and as such everything should work, but it isn't. I could pass in the conversations collection into the detail view, search for the correct object and modify that, but that seems kinda weird? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you updating (put) the conversation in the db, when you mark that conversation as read?

Comment: Yes, I am. (more text to meet minimum character count..)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example. I have contacts instead of messages. In the detail view for a contact you can mark it as selected and the list view is updated accordingly, showing a check mark next to the selected contact. [[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iXU5DZ?p=info)]

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('contacts', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/contacts',
        templateUrl: 'contacts.html',
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.contacts = [{ id:0, name: "Alice" , selected: false}, { id:1, name: "Bob" , selected: false}];
        },
        onEnter: function(){
          console.log("enter contacts");
        }

    })
    .state('contacts.list', {
        url: '/list',
        // loaded into ui-view of parent's template
        templateUrl: 'contacts.list.html',
        onEnter: function(){
          console.log("enter contacts.list");
        }
    })
    .state('contacts.list.detail', {
        url: '/:id',
        // loaded into ui-view of parent's template
        templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html',
        controller: function($scope, $stateParams){
          $scope.person = $scope.contacts[$stateParams.id];
        },
        onEnter: function(){
          console.log("enter contacts.detail");
        }
    })
```

contacts.html

```
<h1>Contacts Page</h1>
<div ui-view></div>
```

contacts.list.html

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="person in contacts">
<a ng-href="#/contacts/list/{{person.id}}">{{person.name}}</a>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <span ng-show= person.selected> {{'\u2713'}} </span>
</li>
</ul>
<div ui-view></div>
```

contacts.detail.html

```
<h2>Details</h2>
Name: {{person.name}} <br/>
Mark as selected: <input type='checkbox' ng-model=person.selected> </input>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've been sick. I like this idea, but it's not going to work for me since the single object (GET /conversations/1) contains more stuff, like the messages, then the items in the list (GET /conversations) have. So I can't really just find the item in the array and return that in the resolve.